# Assign specific line from a variable to another variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, awk, variable

I would like to take a specific line from a variable to another variable.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
c="1.apple
2.banna
3.peach"

read "Please choose fruit [1-3]:" t

a=$c | awk "NR==$t"
echo "You choose: $a"
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you forget the `-p` in `read`?

Comment: a=$(echo $c | awk "NR==$t") ?

Comment: Please don't post answers unless you actually want to answer the question. Have a look at the [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Here String redirection `<<<`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) together with [Command Substitution `$()`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and don't forget to [put double quotes around your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells):

```
a=$(awk "NR==$t" <<< "$c")
```

Comment: Don't forget to put double quotes around command substitution, too!

Comment: @Darkhogg - quoting the command substitution makes no difference here as it is contextually an assignment - not a list. `var=$(: std out of command sub)` is no different than `var="$(: std out of command sub)"` and the former form is a little less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place:

```
read "Please choose fruit [1-3]:" t
```

...will not work. It looks like you're trying to provide a prompt string to the shell builtin `read`, but `read` interprets its first argument as the name of a variable to assign the value of the line it reads from stdin unless it is handed options.

```
read -p "Please choose fruit [1-3]:" t
```

...is an option supported in many shells and is probably nearer to what you intend to do.

That said, you probably shouldn't stack multiple values in a singly delimited assignment unless you have previously settled on a means splitting it out. When you do:

```
var=' some list of things '
```

The shell will eventually parse that out to something like:

```
\0 some list of things \0
```

...and assign the single name to the single value. Many shells offer more advance forms of delimiting - such as named arrays - but all POSIX shells provide at least one easily definable array per function context - the `$@` shell array. Various implementations providing named arrays generally mimic the `$@` shell array behavior for their named arrays as well.

So rather than assigning all of those individual values to a single string as you do, you might do instead:

```
set apple banana peach
```

You can witness the effect of this by addressing each individual value singly by number like:

```
printf %s\\n "$1"
```

...which prints:

```
apple
```

*Note - if you get to using values larger than 9 it is best to enclose the reference in braces like `"${10}"`*

You can address the number of different strings in `"$#"` like:

```
printf %d\\n "$#"
```

...which prints...

```
3
```

You can address the lot of them in a list of separate strings like:

```
printf %s\\n "$@"
```

...which prints:

```
apple
banana
peach
```

...or as a single, concatenated string like:

```
printf %s\\n "$*"
```

...where the separate array value strings are concatenated on the first character contained in the shell variable `$IFS`. So if you have a default `$IFS` value of `<space><tab><newline>` each string in the array will join to the next with a single `<space>` betwixt them. The above command, for example, prints:

```
apple banana peach
```

...but if I do:

```
IFS='fruit sucks'; printf %s\\n "$*"
```

...it prints:

```
applefbananafpeach
```

Most shells that implement named array extensions do so with similar syntax, excepting that the various means of addressing the array must be associated with a name. An array assignment typically looks like:

```
array=( apple banana peach )
```

...or...

```
array[0]=apple array[1]=banana array[2]=peach
```

Compared to `"$1"`, `"$#"`, `"$@"`, `"$*"`, named arrays will usually work like `"${array[1]}"`, `"${#array[@]}"`, `"${array[@]}"`, and `"${array[*]}"` where the previously mentioned relationship between `"$*"` and `"$IFS"` still holds true for `"${array[*]}"`.

Once you have properly delimited your values your problem becomes a much easier one to handle:

```
set apple banana peach; n=0
{   for a do printf "$((n+=1)).:\t%s\n" "$a"; done
    printf "Please choose fruit [1-$#]: "; read t
} <>/dev/tty >&0 &&
[ "0$((!${#t}))" -lt "0${t##*[!0-9]*}" ] &&
eval 'printf "You choose: %s\n" "${'"$t"}\"
```

Some may scoff at the use of `eval` above but its use here is no less safe than many would do like `"${array[$t]}"` *(which is one way you might do this with named arrays)* because `"${array[$t]}"` implies a second evaluation of `$t` as an index after it is first parsed as a string. Without testing it as I do above to ensure that it contains at least one and nothing other than a digit and that it is greater than 0 *(or whatever the shell implementation's minimum named array index might be)* either case could render unintentional results.