# How to access the contents of a file that is used as an argument when running a bash script?

Tags: bash, files, scripting, parameter

I am running a bash script with its parameters/arguments as files. From inside the script, how do I get the contents of those files?

I run the script with this command line:

```
sh script_name animal.txt stars.txt
```

`animal.txt` contains "giraffe".

From the script, how do I get the contents (giraffe) of `animal.txt`? I am very new to bash scripts, so any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If it's a `bash` script why do you call it as `sh ...` and not as `bash ...`?

Comment: I didn't know that there was a difference. My testing up until this point has been OK using sh. I'll start using bash though. Anyway, could you help with my problem?

Comment: Certain features don't work if `bash` is called as `sh`. As long as you don't use the bash-specific features (which is typical for beginners) both ways work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f do exec <"$f"
    : handle stdin
done
```

A non-interactive shell will treat any redirection from a file that cannot be read or that does not exist when associated w/ a special builtin as a fatal error and exit immediately with a meaningful diagnostic message written to stderr. So either your parameters are valid, readable files and the above statement will do nothing useful until you replace the `: ...` part w/ something useful, or the user has provided an invalid parameter and the script exits meaningfully.

When you do...

```
for var in ...; do : compound command list on "$var"; done
```

The `in ...;` bit is an optional statement in the syntax which enables you to substitute a parameter set for the default set - which is your argument list.

So...

```
for var do : compound command list on "$var"; done
```

...is probably what you're looking for, here.

```
for f do exec <"$f"
    : now do some stuff w/ stdin
done
```

...where the shell will iteratively assign to stdin and validate as readable files any arguments provided your script for all commands that follow the `exec` statement until all parameters are exhausted and the `for` loop is `done`. If it cannot do this then it will format and print your error message for you in a standard form to which the user is already accustomed.

Comment: "A non-interactive shell will treat any redirection from a file that cannot be read or that does not exist as a fatal error and exit immediately" – Have you tried that? I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does $@ do? Googling doesn't give any results.

Comment: @eltigre: See the `Special Parameters` section in the bash man page.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - Dang - yes and no. It's for [special builtins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01). I was tired when I wrote that. It is now fixed.

Comment: @eligre - a better reference is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02). I also wrote an [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179754/52934) yesterday or the day before related to the shell array `"$@"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_file="$1"
test -f "$first_file" || exit 2
file_content="$(<"$first_file")"
echo "$file_content"
```

Comment: So I assume file_contents will be a string. Would concatenating it like: a=$file_content$anotherstring work?

Comment: @eltigre Yes. But even though it is not necessary in this case you should get used to quote everything: `a="${file_content}${anotherstring}"`

Comment: Note that `file_content` will contain the content of `$first_file` stripped of all trailing newline characters provided there is no NUL characters in there.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ;
    echo "$line"
    #######
    #######
    ########
done < "$1"
```

description: each $line is a  content of complete line of your file.

```
usage : ./script.sh file.txt
```

Comment: [`while read` loops are best avoided in shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22565)

Comment: Why ? because it read from file not read from keyboard.

Comment: See the link in my previous comment.