# How do you parse through a subdirectory where the path contains spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I'm trying to parse through a set of files in a directory on a mapped drive. However, I can't seem to resolve an issue that seems to be because of spaces in the path to the subdirectory. Would appreciate any help! Thank you.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/user/.gvfs/analysis\$\ on\ server.university.edu/users/username/m/BED_files/*
#FILES=/home/user/Desktop #this works

for f in "${FILES}"
do
    echo $f
done
```

Comment: [Use More Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)...

Comment: Quotes do not seem to resolve the issue. Quote or no quotes, I just get the path echoed.

Comment: `FILES=(path/to/files/*); for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done`

Comment: Space and without space (/home/user/Desktop/*), I get an error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. I understand that you're creating an array containing the /path/to/files, but this isn't working.

Comment: @user1854603 what version of bash are you using?

Comment: @jasonwryan you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Random832 4.2.25

Comment: @user1854603 What is the exact script you are trying and are you sure it is being executed in bash? If it has no #!/bin/bash line or a /bin/sh line it may be executed in another shell. Your error looks like the one produced by dash.

Comment: Script has header + @jasonwryan's bit pasted in with the path modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the wildcard as part of the variable if you are also using quotes. Note that in the array variable syntax @jasonwryan suggested, it is looking at the contents of the directory at the time the array is initialized, rather than when the loop is executed.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
DIR='/home/user/.gvfs/analysis$ on server.university.edu/users/username/m/BED_files'

for f in "$DIR"/*
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

If you really need the wildcard to be defined in a variable, putting it it in a separate one will work:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR='/home/user/.gvfs/analysis$ on server.university.edu/users/username/m/BED_files'
FILES='*.txt'

for f in "$DIR"/$FILES
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have permissions all the way through to the final subdirectory and @jasonwryan answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with an arrayed expansion result in a basic POSIX shell you have to take care with both `$IFS` and filename generation. You can work safely with unquoted variables - but it is usually not the most simple way to do it.

Shell's are designed to work first and foremost with *arguments* - so I suggest you use the argument array:

```
set -- "${FILES%/*}"/*
```

You'll have to check a glob's result though - in any POSIX shell if the glob doesn't resolve it will still remain an iterable parameter. This is true of `for var in glob*` as well - without testing the results you cannot be sure that you're actually working with a file. So...

```
for f do [ -e "$f" ] || [ -L "$f" ] && printf %s\\n "$f"; done
```

You can iterate over the items in your arg array like `for arg do ...;done`. You can also address them from within the loop as `"$1"` `"$2`" and etc, or as a whole with either of `"$@"` and `"$*"` depending. The array remains set when the loop is complete.

One last note though, as I mentioned before, filename generation is a configurable feature of the shell. It can be disabled w/ `set -f` or enabled w/ `set +f`. What's more, it only works if there are matching filenames in the directory in which you search - if there are none, you just get your unresolved glob back. Globbing also requires both search and execute permissions for a directory. So, if you find you cannot resolve a glob match, you might try enabling filename generation, checking the path's permissions, and verifying there are files there in the first place.

Comment: bash bash the `shopt -s nullglob` option which is handy to replace the pattern with nothing if there are no matches. For ksh93, use `~(N)pattern*` for the same effect.

Comment: This `set -- 1 2 3 4; for arg do; echo $arg; done` (without a semicolon before "do") throws an error in bash and dash. It iterates properly in ksh and zsh.

Comment: OK, I've been schooled. Apologies for the hard-headedness.

Comment: @glennjackman - no sweat - there was no offense taken here - i like talking about that stuff. And if you don't get a little learning at the answers site every once in a while, it might be hard to justify coming back. Anyway, i like that form because I like being able to refer to the arg array as whole before, after, and during - and numbered is just easier for me. I also like changing the array while I iterate - doing `for arg do set inner loop arg array` is just fine. There are probably better links on the subject, but [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179991/52934) is ok