# UNIX KSH/BASH Call by Reference using Array (at GNU bash 4.2)

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

I am new to Unix shell scripting
My code is as follows:

```
  i=0
for var in 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
do
  content[i]=var
  ((i=`expr i+1`))
done
a=10
b=50
c=40
d=90
e=100
Now I wanted to print the local variables contents using array into the function

print_array
{
echo "${content[0]}"
echo "${content[1]}"
echo "${content[2]}"
echo "${content[3]}"
echo "${content[4]}"
}
```

what I wanted to do that array contents are {a,b,c,d,e}
and there is a local variables named a,b,c,d,e
with some assigned values
I wanted to print those local variables through the use of array since the name 
of array element and local variable element is same so I tried to call by reference by trying multiple combinations of $ and array_names but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll define an indirect printing function first...

```
_print() while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
         do    printf '$%s = %d\n' \
                       "$1" "$(($1))"
               shift
         done
```

Next I'll setup the array and increment...

```
arr=( a b c d e ); i=0
for var in "${arr[@]}"
do  : "$(($var=(i+=10)))"
done
```

So now the value of `$a` is 10 and `$b` 20 and so on. Last there remains only to print...

```
_print "${arr[@]}"
```

...which prints to stdout...

```
$a = 10
$b = 20
$c = 30
$d = 40
$e = 50
```

All of this works because of the way the shell handles `$((`math`))` expansions - they're basically `eval`s. In an arithmetic expansion the shell *first* expands *any* other valid shell expansion before attempting to do the math - making the actual math its last order of business.

This means that if you do:

```
i=a a=10; echo "$(($i))"
```

The printed result is `10` because the shell expands the value of `$i` to get `a` then evaluates *that* result as an integer reference.

The above will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

This means I could possibly also have done...

```
i=10
for var in a b c d e
do  arr[($var=i*${#arr[@]}+i)/i]=$var
done
```

...to handle array assignment, index evaluation, and `$var` integer assignment at once because the `[`index`]` brackets of a named shell array - in a shell which supports them - are treated identically to the `$((`expansion`))` parens of a math expression.

Running the above code wrapped in `ksh -xc` command prints the following debug output to standard error:

```
+ arr[1]=a
+ arr[2]=b
+ arr[3]=c
+ arr[4]=d
+ arr[5]=e
```

From there I can just do:

```
echo "$((${arr[1]}))"
echo "$((a))"
```

...to print...

```
10
10
```

...because they evaluate to the same thing in shells which support named arrays. However, in shells which don't...

```
echo 'arr=(a b c d e)' | bash -x
+ arr=(a b c d e)     #bash traces the successful command to stderr
echo 'arr=(a b c d e)' | sh -x
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected   #sh traces something else
```

So in the `_print()` function I just `shift` over the positional parameters *(which represents a truly portable shell `"$@"`array)* while there are any at all and `printf`...

1. First a `$` dollar sign.
2. Then the `%s`tring value stored in my `$1`st positional parameter.
3. Then an `=` equals sign.
4. And last the value stored in the *value stored in* my `$(($1))` first positional parameter.

As the function `shift`s its arguments away the first positional parameter is constantly being replaced with the next until the `$#` count of positionals equals 0 and the function returns.

Before running the function when I initialize the array and its constituent indirection variables that works like this:

- `for var in "${arr[@]}"`

  - The shell will expand `[@]` to a *list* of arguments and `[*]` to a single concatenation of that list. If the expansion is not quoted it *might* also expand `[*]` out to a list as well - depending on whether or not there is a value for `$IFS` when it is done and how `set -f`ilename expansion is currently configured - but if it does so it likely does not do it the way you intend.
- `: "$(($var=(i+=10)))"`

  - Each value in `${arr[@]}` is assigned to the value of `$var` in turn. `$(($var=(i+=10)))` is then expanded *first* for the value in `$var` like `$((a=(i+=10)))` and last of all the math is done - which first increments `$i` by 10 and next assigns the value of `$i` to `$a`.

Comment: @mikerserv It is giving error 0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `(' is not expected. means at this line arr=( a b c d e ); i=0 then I have changed it to arr= 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' then error message  a:  not found is coming please guide me to solve it thanks a lot for your descriptive answer :)

Comment: @Aman - `a: not found` sounds like you're trying to run a command. Which version of `ksh`?

Comment: I am running on bash 4.2

Comment: @Aman - well, then you must have entered something in wrong - everything up there works in `bash` - at least it does  on my system. Have you tried it since edited it? It shouldn't make a difference though...

Comment: I am going to retest it.

Comment: -bash-4.2$ cat >lastexp.ksh
_print() while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]
         do    printf '$%s = %d\n' \
                       "$1" "$(($1))"
               shift
         done
 arr=( a b c d e ); i=0
for var in "${arr[@]}"
do  : "$(($var=(i+=10)))"
done
_print "${arr[@]}"  
^C
-bash-4.2$ sh lastexp.ksh
lastexp.ksh[6]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `(' is not expected.

Comment: @Aman  - you're trying to enter it all in on one line? And what is *lastexp.ksh*? You can't do that. Where there are line breaks in the command examples you need line breaks - either that or semi-colons. If you want to do it at the terminal prompt you can, but enter it in by line as it is presented. I guess I could make a copy/paste version for you if you want. A tip, by the way - to enter a `\n`ewline at your prompt you can probably use CTRL+V then CTRL+J. Your error though is due to the function and array definition running together - it would need to be `done; arr=(` at that point,

Comment: @Aman - here is that command all on a single line, if you really want it that way: `_print() while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do printf '$%s = %d\n' "$1" "$(($1))"; shift; done;arr=( a b c d e ); i=0;for var in "${arr[@]}";do : "$(($var=(i+=10)))";done;_print "${arr[@]}";` Maybe also try: `i=25; for var in a b c d e; do  arr[($var=i*${#arr[@]}+i)/i]=$var; done` and afterward running `_print "${arr[@]}"` again - the results are the same, except that you can put different numbers in `i` and it will increment automatically. So `i=3` will increment each assigned `$var` by three as they are assigned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22632/discussion-between-aman-and-mikeserv).

Comment: again not working -bash-4.2$ cat > testksh.ksh
_print() while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do printf '$%s = %d\n' "$1" "$(($1))"; shift; done;arr=( a b c d e ); i=0;for var in "${arr[@]}";do : "$(($var=(i+=10)))";done;_print "${arr[@]}";
^C
-bash-4.2$ sh testksh.ksh
testksh.ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `(' is not expected.

Comment: @Aman Oh, yeah, of course not. You're invoking `sh` - not `bash`. While it's possible the two share the same executable *(which is true of some systems)* `bash` doesn't do arrays when invoked as `sh` because it goes into POSIX conformance mode. You won't have any luck with this at all that way. And what is this *testksh.ksh* stuff? Anyway, there *are* arrays *(of my own preferred)* in POSIX-mode - but those are the positional arrays which are created one per function - *(I use one above when working with `$1`)* but that's a different thing than named arrays. There's no - `arr[index]=` either.

Comment: @Aman - see the edit I made here and maybe see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179754/52934).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#i=0
for var in 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
do
  content[${#content[*]}]=$var  # or content[i++]=$var
done
# or just content=( 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' )
a=10
b=50
c=40
d=90
e=100
for i in "${#content[@]}"
do
  echo ${!i}
done
```

Comment: Getting Error :${!i}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command. @Costas

Comment: @Aman `bash -version` ? I have `GNU bash 4.3.11`

Comment: I have bash 4.2

Comment: Try `eval j=\$$i;echo $j` (and I correct the code above `var` --> `$var`, so try it again)

Comment: I have tried the same but still not working

Comment: Try simple test `a=b ; b=5 ; echo ${!a}` and show output here

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want an indirection in variable's access with, e.g., `bash`. With this code:

```
content=( a b c d e )

a=10
b=50
c=40
d=90
e=100

echo "${!content[0]}"
echo "${!content[1]}"
echo "${!content[2]}"
echo "${!content[3]}"
echo "${!content[4]}"
```

You will get this result:

```
10
50
40
90
100
```

The key here is `bash`'s specific variable expansion access method `"${! ... }"`.

Comment: I have bash 4.2 which does not support echo "${!content[4]}" mentioned process substitution please guide me :)

Comment: @Aman; the construct that I proposed is certainly running even in old `bash` versions. In **every** proposed solution you claim you are running a `bash` and getting errors. So I have to say I have my doubts that what you say is true! - Try two things: `bash --version`, and (instead of calling your script as `./yourscript`) call your script **explicitly** with `bash yourscript`.

Comment: @Aman; I just see in an analysis of another poster's answer that you are running `sh` and not `bash`. So use the form I proposed to call your script, `bash yourscript`, and everything should work fine.